# pdf protecting with joomla extension

Tags: development, extensions

I'm developing a Joomla site.

There are 3 features needed:
- file management, to grant access to an user to certain PDF files
- PDF edit to insert the user's name
- PDF edit to protect the pdf with the user's password

For example, an user logs in and the site redirects to the download page and allow access to several PDF files.

If he downloads a PDF file, that PDF must have his name at the bottom (or as a watermark) and must be protected for opening with the same password the user uses in Joomla.

There are Joomla extensions to provide PDF file management, but there aren't any extensions with the functionality to insert the user's name and protect it with a password.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: I doubt an off the shelf extension will do your requirements. I think you will need to build or have built a custom application using a pdf creation library like https://tcpdf.org

Answer (score 1):

Could you clarify if it's ok if  the watermark itself can later be removed by the user or does it need to be permanent as a form of DRM. If you need that level of protection Adobe Lifecycle, if it's still called that, probably has something to do it.

Comment: the ideal is to be permanent